# drawing a splom() graphic using as.data.frame

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

I need to build a `splom()` graphic using `lattice` package with `as.data.frame` function, but it doesn't work.

```
library(lattice)
data(Investment, package = "sandwich")
Investment <- as.data.frame(Investment, GNP)
splom(Investment|"Graphic", xlab = "Investment", ylab = "GNP")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(lattice)
data(Investment, package = "sandwich")
Investment <- as.data.frame(Investment)

splom(
  x = Investment[c("Investment", "GNP")], 
  main = "Graphic"
)
```